# How to delete zip file while unzipping it with WinRAR

Tags: zip, archiving, winrar

I am going to unzip a 35GB zip file with winrar but i only have 37GB of space, so i will only have 2GB  of space after downloading the zip file, how do i replace the zip after unzipping it instantly so i can unzip the zip without having double amount of space needed for the file?
sorry for my english

edit: Thank you for your kind answers :)

Comment: Short answer: You can't. Free up some disk space first. You could consider temporarily zipping some other stuff to make space.

Comment: @DavidPostill: Yes, IMO if it's worthy enough to begin with "Short answer:" then it's worthy enough to be posted as one... I think there's nothing wrong with one-line answer posts (they can be edited or expanded by others anyway).

Comment: @user1686 Done.

Answer (score 1):

#### I want to unzip a zip file but there is insufficient space on the disk.

That is not possible  without creating enough space on the disk.

- You should of course clean up your disk first. There may be many files you no longer need, like for example the contents of any temp directories.
- You don't specify your operating system but many modern operating systems include built in disk clean-up software.
- You may be able to move files around to other disks or mounts points as well.

If you have done all of this and you still do not have enough space then make some temporary space by:

1. zipping some files (preferably highly compressible ones),
2. delete the files you have just zipped (be careful not to delete the new zips),
3. repeat 1. and 2. until you have enough space,
4. download your zip and unzip it,
5. delete the downloaded zip,
6. unzip the files you created in step 1 (do this one file at a time and remove the corresponding zip before moving to the next file).

Answer (score 0):

If you can move the file to a networked device, you can unzip it to the device with only 37GB available.